# How to convert labelled feature variable to categorical values?

Tags: matlab

I have imported an Excel sheet to MATLAB as table. Some of the columns have values like ('Yes','No') and ('A','B','C','D').

How can I convert these values to numeric values?

Answer (score 0):

I give an example that you can extend to your problem later:

Here I have a cell, considering imported into matlab, and I want to replace the elements with true (1), if the element is 'Y' and false (0) otherwise:

```
D = {'Y','N','N','Y','N'};
    'Y'    'N'    'N'    'Y'    'N'

cellfun(@(x)(x=='Y'),D)
ans =

     1     0     0     1     0
```